# Error during removing an element from a 2D array

Tags: python

In a 285 x 507 array, I am trying to find the lowest seam and remove it using pop.
I have the below problem while using pop.

Code:

```
    for i in range(0, len(img)):
       for j in range(0, len(img[0]):
            a[i].pop(j)
```

Can anyone please help me why this error comes "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pop'"
and how to rectify

Note: This works perectly fine in a 5x5 array. when it comes to huge dimensions,I seem to be facing issues

Comment: this does not work for a 5 by 5 array either, what is img and what is a?

Comment: Don't delete stuff from a list/array, as you're iterating over it

Comment: It can't possibly work for a 5x5 array, because `numpy` arrays don't have a `pop` method -- just as the error says. It could work for a (Python) list of (Python) lists, but that's totally different from an array.

Comment: This is not a numpy array by creation. But I had to convert an image to a 2D array by using hSobel and VSobel values of the image which yields me the energy values of every pixel.  img is the 2D array (285 x 507) which has the energy values of each pixel.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things numpy doesnt use `pop()` but instead you can use `delete()`

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am wondering whether is it possible to delete a single element using numpy.delete ?

Comment: `np.delete` does not happen in-place so you are not removing from the original array as arrays are immutable

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure mine is an immutable array. I guess it is more of a 2D list. I am stuck as to how to remove an element in the 2D list.

Comment: okay. I understand It does not do in-place deletion and I shld assign the result to another array. Is it not possible to do a single element deletion? Thanks